# Python ошибка в классах

Tags: python

Ребят, подскажите в чем проблема. Пишу адресную книгу по книге Byte of Python.

```
import pickle

class PhoneBook():
    mybook = {}
    def add_person(self, newcont, new_phone):
        self.newcont = newcont
        self.new_phone = new_phone
        PhoneBook.mybook[self.newcont] = self.new_phone
        f = open('mybook.txt', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(PhoneBook.mybook, f)
        f.close()
```

При вызове следующего блока (вне класса) выдает ошибку:

```
newcont = input('Введите имя нового контакта: ')
new_phone = input('Введите телефон этого человека: ')
PhoneBook.add_person(newcont, new_phone)

PhoneBook.add_person(newcont, new_phone) 
TypeError: add_person() missing 1 required positional argument: 'new_phone'
```

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к методу add_person через класс PhoneBook. В методе 3 аргумента, первый из которых self. У вас получается self=newcont, newcont=new_phone, а аргумент new_phone вообще не передается, хотя обязательный. Надо работать с инстантом класса PhoneBook.

Comment: Параметр `self` передается автоматически для экземпляров класса, на сам класс это не распространяется.

Comment: Не используйте расширение текстового файла для работы с двоичными данными (`pickle`), чтобы потом себя же не запутать при чтении. И причем тут `django`?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы пытаетесь вызвать метод экземпляра `PhoneBook` напрямую из его класса.

Классы в python являются объектами. Каждый класс имеет своё собственное пространство имён. Все переменные и функции которые объявлены в классе находятся в его пространстве имён и могут быть доступны в виде атрибутов объекта класса.

Функции определённые в классе доступны экземплярам класса в виде методов.

У Методов и функций есть 2 важных отличия. Функции не привязаны ни к каким объектам, никакие параметры им не передаются сами собой. Методы всегда привязаны к какому либо объекту (экземпляру), метод всегда получает экземпляр класса в качестве своего первого параметра (обычно его именуют `self`).

Когда создаётся экземпляр класса все функции определённые в классе становятся его методами.

Пример:

```
class PhoneBook: 
    #код PhoneBook

print( PhoneBook.add_person ) 
# напечетает что это просто функция
# лежащая в пространстве имен PhoneBook

my_book = PhoneBook()
print( my_book.add_person )
# напишет что это bound метод (не функция!)

my_book.add_person(newcont, new_phone)
# происходит вызов метода (первый параметр будет передан автоматически)

# это эквивалентно следующему вызову
PhoneBook.add_person(my_book, newcont, new_phone)
```

В вашем коде `PhoneBook.add_person(newcont, new_phone)` вы вызваете функцию с тремя параметрами, но передаёте ей только 2 параметра. Из-за этого получаете ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо! !!!!!!